# Highlight values in ploty

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Below is the dataframe that is been plotted in plotly. But I wanted to highlight values that are 0. For example, column A has 0 values. I need to highlight them in graph. Is it possible?

```
df <- structure(
  list(
   day = structure(c(18262, 18266, 18273, 18280,
                            18287, 18294), class = "Date"),
    A = c(9L, 8L, 4L, 0L,
              0L, 7L),
    `B` = c(3L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 3L)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, 6L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
  day            A          B
1 2020-01-01     9          3
2 2020-01-05     8          6
3 2020-01-12     4         10
4 2020-01-19     0          6
5 2020-01-26     0          8
6 2020-02-02     7          3
> plot_ly(df) %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = FALSE)) %>% add_trace(x = ~day, y = ~A, type = 'scatter', mode = "lines", yaxis = "y1", line = list (color = 'red'), name = 'A') 
%>% add_trace(x = ~day, y = ~B, type = 'scatter', mode = "lines", yaxis = "y1", line = list (color = 'black'), name = 'B')
```

Comment: dput your df....type `dput(df)` in console. Copy-paste the result here.

Comment: From your reputation, it seems you are not new around here, so you should know how to ask a question in a way that makes it easy for people to try your example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask For example, by providing the code to generate the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation:

```
?plotly::add_trace
```

`add_trace()` has a `data` argument. You can provide different slices of your data to different layers. So, make a layer with just the data that has the values you want to highlight, and a layer with all the other values. Or a trace with all the data and a layer with just the data you want to highlight.

Something like this:

```
plot_ly(df) %>% 
    layout(yaxis = list(title = FALSE)) %>% 
    add_trace(x = ~day, y = ~A, type = 'scatter', mode = "lines", yaxis = "y1", line = list (color = 'red'), name = 'A') %>% 
    add_trace(x = ~day, y = ~B, type = 'scatter', mode = "lines", yaxis = "y1", line = list (color = 'black'), name = 'B') %>%
    add_markers(data=df[df$A==0, ], x = ~day, y = ~A, type = 'scatter', yaxis = "y1", name = 'zeros')
```